# Show and Hide table from another table

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to show a table after clicking on a link, but it only works if the link is out side of the table, but once the link is inside of a table it just don't work, I'm wondering why? May be  there is a better way of doing this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
<title>Show and Hide</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript">    </script>
<script>
$(function () {

$('.reply-comment').on('click', function (e) {

 e.preventDefault();
 var form = $(this).next('.reply-form');
 var CommentID = $(this).attr('id');

 if (form.is(':visible')) {

   // hide it
   form.hide(function () {

     $('#' + CommentID).html('<a href="" class="reply-comment" id="reply-comment-' + CommentID + '"> Reply </a>');

    });

  }else {

    // show it
    form.show(function () {

      $('#' + CommentID).html('<a href="" class="reply-comment" id="reply-comment-' + CommentID + '"> Cancel </a>');

     });

  }

 });

 });
</script>

<style>
.reply-form {

   display:none;

}
</style>

</head>

<body>
  <div>Start stuff etc etc...</div>
<br />

<table   width="300" border="1" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
  <td> Start </td>
  <td> <!-- this will not work, why? -->
    <a href="" id="17" class="reply-comment"> Reply </a>
  </td>
  <td> Out </td>
</tr>
</table>


 <br> <!-- this works, but I can't use like this -->
 <!-- a href="" id="1" class="reply-comment"> Reply </a --> 

 <div class="reply-form well">
 <br />
<table width="300" border="1" bgcolor="#1A1A1A" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
 <tr>
   <td><form name="reply-form" id="repl-form" method="POST">

     <textarea name="Comment" rows="6" class="span10"></textarea>
     <br />
     <br />
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary replycommentsubmitbutton" value="Reply" />

  </td></form>
<tr>
</table>
</div>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div>More stuff here etc etc...</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: show us a demo at jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with

```
var form = $(this).next('.reply-form');
```

`next()` in jquery is defined as follows:

> Description: Get the immediately following sibling of each element in
>   the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves
>   the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

Although the code below is not the best solution, but it works for the specific example.  I would re-write it to better fit the solution you are working on:

```
var form = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.reply-form');
```

or simply

```
var form = $('.reply-form');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4CMcY/) Sample

Answer (score 1):

Swap this piece of code

> var form = $(this).next('.reply-form');

with:

> var form = $('.reply-form');